# Rerport rdlc reportprocessingexception comparisonerror

Tags: .net, visual-studio, reporting, rdlc

I have some detailed report with grouping. Data comes from dataset. One group expression is simple IIF statement (I tried Switch too). But the report just show the error:

> reportprocessingexception_comparison Error was thrown

How can I debug this? I've tried "everything" and I still have no clue. Data is fine, I tried comparing with boolean, integer and string value.

This is my group expression:

```
=IIf(Fields!grouping1.Value.Equals("y"),Fields!x_desc.Value,Fields!Line.Value)
```

Error looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Both True and False fields have to be of the same type! So I simply added ToString to the second (integer) field:

```
=IIf(Fields!grouping1.Value.Equals("y"),Fields!x_desc.Value,Fields!Line.Value.ToString)
```